# Minima point is a solution point

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, optimization

Consider $$f:\left[0, \dfrac{\pi}2\right] \to \mathbb R$$ defined as $$f(x)=\sup\{x^2,\cos x\}.$$ It is easy to show that $f$ has an absolute minimum point at $x_o \in I$ , but how to show that $\cos x_o=x_o^2$ ?

Answer (score 1):

$f$ has an absolute minimum point because of Weierstrass Theorem. By Fermat's theorem if the function is defined in a neighbourhood of a minimum point and is differentiable at the minimum point, then the derivative in that point is zero (critical point). So the minimum point can be:

1. a point on the boundary of the domain,
2. a point where the derivative of $f$ is zero,
3. a point where $f$ is not differentiable.

Points of type 3 are points where $x^2=\cos x$ because in the neighborhood of every other point (say when $\cos x > x^2$) the function is equal to a differentiable function (say $\cos x$) and hence it is differentiable.

Points of type 2 are found solving $f'(x)=0$ and points of type 1 are $0$ and $\pi/2$. You can find all of them and see where you find the minimum value of $f$. To discard these candidate points you can also consider the monotonicity of $f$ as suggested in the other answer.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the function $g(x) = x^2$ and $h(x) = \cos(x)$ separately.

Both functions are non negative. This means that $f(x) \geq 0 ~\forall x \in I$.

Notice that $g(x)$ is monotonically increasing and $h(x)$ is decreasing in $I$. Their images are:

$$\mathcal{I}(g, I) = \left[0, \frac{\pi^2}{4}\right] ~\text{and}~ \mathcal{I}(h, I) = \left[0, 1\right]$$

Since $\mathcal{I}(g, I) \cap \mathcal{I}(h, I) \neq \emptyset$, then ther must exists an $x_0 \in I$ such that $g(x_0) = h(x_0)$. This implies that:

$$h(x) > g(x) ~ \forall x \in [0, x_0) \Rightarrow f(x) = h(x)$$
and
$$h(x) < g(x) ~ \forall x \in \left(x_0, \frac{\pi}{2}\right] \Rightarrow f(x) = g(x)$$

At this point, it's clear that $f(x)$ attains its minimum for $x = x_0$. Indeed:

$$f(x) = h(x) > h(x_0) ~ \forall x \in [0, x_0) ~\text{(since $h(x)$ is monotonically decreasing)}$$
and
$$f(x) = g(x) > g(x_0) ~ \forall x \in \left(x_0, \frac{\pi}{2}\right]  ~\text{(since $g(x)$ is monotonically increasing)}$$